# How can I render a new image on a flask html template without replacing the previous one? (python)

Tags: python, html, image, flask

I'm building an image editing application using python and flask, and want two or more user images to display as they are uploaded. One image works fine, but when the next one is uploaded it replaces the previous image in the same space rather than appearing on the page with the previous image. I feel like I'm missing something significant and can't figure out what it is.

Here is how I have it set up at the moment:

Python:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_content():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part')
        return redirect(request.url)
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No image selected for uploading')
        return redirect(request.url)
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        print('upload_image filename: ' + filename, os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        flash('Image successfully uploaded and displayed below')
        global content
        content = cv2.imread(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']+'/'+filename), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        return render_template('index.html', filename=filename)
    else:
        flash('Allowed image types are - png, jpg, jpeg, gif')
        return redirect(request.url)

#copy of method for style
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_style():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part')
        return redirect(request.url)
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No image selected for uploading')
        return redirect(request.url)
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filenamejr = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filenamejr))
        print('upload_image filename: ' + filenamejr, os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filenamejr))
        flash('Image successfully uploaded and displayed below')
        global style
        style = cv2.imread(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']+'/'+filenamejr), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        #content = image.img_to_array(content, dtype='uint8')
        return display_image(filenamejr)
    else:
        flash('Allowed image types are - png, jpg, jpeg, gif')
        return redirect(request.url)


@app.route('/display/<filename>')
def display_image(filename):
    return redirect(url_for('static', filename='uploads/' + filename), code=301)
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <h2>Select a content image to upload</h2>
    <p>
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
          {% if messages %}
            <ul>
            {% for message in messages %}
              <li>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
    </p>
        <div>
            <img src="{{ url_for('display_image', filename=filename) }}">
        </div>
    <form method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <dl>
            <p>
                <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" required>
            </p>
        </dl>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info">
        </p>
    </form>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript>
        $(function() {
          $('a#test').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            $.getJSON('/maskInter/',
                function() {
              //do nothing
            });
            return false;
          });
        });
    </script>

<div class="row">
  <h2>Select a style image to upload</h2>
  <p>
      {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
          <ul>
          {% for message in messages %}
            <li>{{ message }}</li>
          {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        {% endif %}
      {% endwith %}
  </p>
      <div>
          <img src="{{ url_for('display_image', filename=filenamejr) }}">
      </div>
  <form method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <dl>
          <p>
              <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" required>
          </p>
      </dl>
      <p>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info">
      </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with a great deal of assistance from my advisor. In case anyone runs into a similarly specific issue here it is:

The solution was to combine the two python methods using the session library in flask, specify variables for content and style within the conjoined method, and modify if statements to handle the differences. This allowed us to simplify both the python and html.

app.py:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
 
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_content():
    if not any(f in ['content_file', 'style_file'] for f in request.files):
        flash('No file part')
        return redirect(request.url)
    submitted_file = 'content_file' if 'content_file' in request.files else 'style_file'
    file = request.files[submitted_file]
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No image selected for uploading')
        return redirect(request.url)
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        session[submitted_file] = filename
        print('upload_image filename: ' + filename, os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        flash('Image successfully uploaded and displayed below') 
        return render_template('index.html')
    else:
        flash('Allowed image types are - png, jpg, jpeg, gif')
        return redirect(request.url)
```

index.html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <h2>Select a content image to upload</h2>
    <p>
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
          {% if messages %}
            <ul>
            {% for message in messages %}
              <li>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
    </p>
        <div>
            <img src="{{ url_for('display_image', filename=session['content_file']) }}">
        </div>
    <form method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <dl>
            <p>
                <input type="file" name="content_file" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" required>
            </p>
        </dl>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info">
        </p>
    </form>

<div class="row">
  <h2>Select a style image to upload</h2>
  <p>
      {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
          <ul>
          {% for message in messages %}
            <li>{{ message }}</li>
          {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        {% endif %}
      {% endwith %}
  </p>
      <div>
          <img src="{{ url_for('display_image', filename=session['style_file']) }}">
      </div>
  <form method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <dl>
          <p>
              <input type="file" name="style_file" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" required>
          </p>
      </dl>
      <p>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info">
      </p>
  </form>
</div>
```